# Get PrepareStament Variable in Scala

Tags: scala, jdbc, prepared-statement

I would like to make the prepareStatement serializable

A preparedStatement is not serializable. I have to build a serializable structure that wraps the call and the parameters to control the construction of the said statement during the deserialization

Here are the classes I created to wrap the PrepareStament

```
import java.sql._
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.util
import java.util.Collections
import avro.shaded.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.mutable

class WrappedConnection(var delegate: Connection) extends Serializable {
  def prepareStatement(sql: String): WrappedPreparedStatement = {
    val ps = delegate.prepareStatement(sql)
    new WrappedPreparedStatement(sql, ps)
  }
  // delegate all Connection methods to the delegate
}

class WrappedPreparedStatement(var sql: String, var delegate: PreparedStatement) extends Serializable {
  private var parameters: mutable.Map[Integer, Object] = mutable.Map.empty[Integer, Object]
  override def toString: String = sql

  def apply( delegateVar: PreparedStatement) {

    delegate = delegateVar
    parameters =   mutable.Map.empty[Integer, Object]
  }

  def getParameters = parameters

  // TODO: many methods to delegate

  @throws[SQLException]
  def setString(parameterIndex: Int, x: String): Unit = {
    delegate.setString(parameterIndex, x)
    parameters.put(parameterIndex, x)
  }
  @throws[SQLException]
  def executeQuery = { // perhaps you might want to do some logging here?
    delegate.executeQuery
  }
  // delegate all PreparedStatement methods to the delegate
}

object WrappedConnection {
  def apply(delegate: Connection): WrappedConnection = new WrappedConnection(delegate)
}
```

This is the test code

```
    val connection = MsSqlUtils.createConnectionFactory(config)
    val conn = connection()
    val wrapperConn = WrappedConnection(conn)
    val statement = wrapperConn.prepareStatement("select * from users")
```

Currently, my problem is to access the variables of my prepareStatement object and create get functions that will return them.
When I talk about variables I talk about the one shown in the picture below not the one in the querie
[image]

Anyone know how to access these variables?

Comment: Any reason for using plain jdbc when we have a lot of great libraries for interacting with SQL databases.

Comment: I use Jdbc because I work with jdbc format used by sparksession to read data from SQL

Comment: Why does this need to be serializable? Needing serializability is already a code smell, but requiring serializability of something that has stateful dependencies on a network connection (to a database), sounds like a mistake. Maybe you need to partition your design differently, so - if you really need serializability - you can serialize the unit-of-work, instead of the implementation to execute that unit-of-work.

Comment: Would rather use existing DB library ([Anorm](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/), Doobie, Slick, ...)